# Deprecated getChildPosition() in recyclerview in android

Tags: android

Deprecated method: `getChildPosition()` method in recyclerview has been deprecated.
What is alternate of this ?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

`getChildPosition` method is deprecated.
you can use `getChildAdapterPosition(View)` or `getChildLayoutPosition(View)`.

Comment: Thank you @Ram it's working fine : getChildAdapterPosition(View)

Comment: If I understood it right, `getChildAdapterPosition` is the natural choice, while `getChildLayoutPosition` returns the position "as of last layout pass"

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
int position = getAdapterPosition();
```